# Cutting part of image and saving to file in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Lets assume i have image 'image.jpg'.
I want to choose part of it with `imrect` function, and save to new file 'newimg.jpg'.
Do you have any idea how to implement in a simple way?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `imcrop` function to cut out the region, and then `imwrite` to save it into a separate image.